How to share a mediaPipe webgl texture to my own webgl program?
I currently using mediaPipe to segment a video stream and extract the background from it (for blurring).
Things seems to work fine.
I'm giving an OffscreenCanvas to mediaPipe in order for it to do the computation on the GPU.
What I'm trying to do now is to bring back the confidenceMask texture from the mediaPipe's program to my own program that doesn't the blurring and mixing.
But when trying to bind the texture and assign it to a uniform, I get the WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: uniform1i: location is not from the associated program
Here is my code so far
  const glCanvas = new OffscreenCanvas(width, height);
  const segmenter = ImageSegmenter.createFromOptions(video, {
    baseOptions: {
      modelAssetPath: QualitySettings.segmentationModel,
      delegate: 'GPU',
    },
    canvas: glCanvas,
    runningMode: 'VIDEO',
    outputConfidenceMasks: true,
  });

  //...
  segmenter.segmentForVideo(videoEl, startTimeMs, result => {
    //...
    gl.useProgram(myProgram);
    //...
    const mask = result.confidenceMasks[0].getAsWebGLTexture();
    const maskLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'u_mask');
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE3);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, mask);
    gl.uniform1i(maskLocation, 3); // ❌ this throws the "location is not from the associated program" error
  });

Is there anything I could do to transfer the texture from the mediaPipe program to my own program.
If not, how am I supposed to use the getAsWebglTexture method?
Thanks for your help

I have tried this answer here, but I seem to get the same error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140893/webgl-share-texture-with-other-program-shader

How did you use the resulted texture in a different GL context?

Actually I realized that in my flow, the gl.useProgram(myProgram); was called only after gl.uniform1i(maskLocation, 3);, which caused the problem.

Is it practical to do all GL initializations inside segmentForVideo callback? It seems like a lot of unnecessary code?
